# How to animate bootstrap popover while showing?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-animate, popover, bootstrap-popover

I've created my custom bs popover and is working properly. I want to animate it while showing. How can I give my custom animation ? Code is very simple as shown below.

```
$("#userPopover").popover({
    trigger: "hover focus",
    delay: {show: 1000, hide: 400},
    placement: 'bottom',
    html: true,
    content: $(".tt-container").html(),
});
```

Comment: Can you provide the current code or a demo?

Comment: @IrvinDomininakaEdward : Hello, I've put the code in question. Thanks

Comment: @IrvinDomininakaEdward : Hello Irvin, as per your answer, I've put the code and it was very useful, the only issue is, for the first time it doesn't animate and everytime while i hover for popover, it gives me error in console. Kindly look at the video: http://youtu.be/DGJ7BPubVgo . Thanks :)

Comment: @IrvinDomininakaEdward : I'm using bootstrap v3.2.0. I've modified the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8uKA5/5/ , the first part of code is to prevent hiding popover while mouse is over it. I've took the reference of http://jsfiddle.net/Zf3m7/463/ for the first part of code. Can you help me out finding my mistake ?The edited fiddle is having the same problem I'm facing and giving same error on console.

Comment: Thanks a lot dear, The only problem left it does not animate the popover for the first time. Can you help me on this please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting from a similar question on `hide` ([How to customize Twitter Bootstrap popover hide animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21700886/how-to-customize-twitter-bootstrap-popover-hide-animation)) you can extend Bootstrap to handle a `show` function, and inside it fire a custom animation.

Code:

```
(function () {

    var orig = $.fn.popover,
        proto = $.extend({}, $.fn.popover.Constructor.prototype);

    $.fn.popover = function (options) {
        return this.each(function () {
            orig.call($(this), options);
            if (typeof options.show == 'function') {
                $(this).data('bs.popover').show = function () {
                    options.show.call(this.$tip, this);
                    proto.show.call(this);
                };
            }
        });
    }

})();
```

Usage:

```
$("#userPopover").popover({
    trigger: "hover focus",
    delay: {
        show: 1000,
        hide: 400
    },
    placement: 'bottom',
    html: true,
    content: $(".tt-container").html(),
    show: function () {
        $(this).fadeIn('slow');
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/8uKA5/

Comment: `Tooltip.prototype.show` already exists, the bootstrap prototyping above is completely waste of time. Proof here -> **http://jsfiddle.net/cjXGE/3/** basically, just use the native `show` , but I have the feeling that OP not just want a hide effect, but something different?

Comment: @davidkonrad nope, in your case the function is not fired

Comment: @davidkonrad : Irvin is right here. native show/hide aren't fired.

Comment: @Dharmraj I'll take a look asap at the first animation that isn't fired

Comment: @IrvinDomininakaEdward : That's very kind of you. You really helped me a lot :) Kindly inform me with a solution if you get the one :) Thanks again.

Comment: @IrvinDomininakaEdward : Heya, the reason might be line #28 of javascript in the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/8uKA5/6/ , that calls original bootstrap with options. Can you give me a workaround ? Thanks.

Comment: @Dharmraj seems because first time in the show function this refers to window and not to the popover element...strange!